# MemoryDB intermittent data missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, devops, redis-cluster, amazon-memory-db

I am seeing key data intermittently missing from the MemoryDB cluster. I have a cluster with 2 shards and some test keys set. I am seeing the behavior that sometimes data comes when I query KEYS and its values and sometimes it is returning empty and later re-populates data on re-connecting. Attaching the image for more details. thanks[image]